# How to give Java keywords inside an enum in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, enums, keyword

I want my `enum` to contains fields that actually are Java keywords. This gives a syntax error. Here is what I'm trying:

```
public enum RuleScopeType{
    private,
    public
}
```

If not possible, suggest some alternatives which could help me achieve the same using some sort of autoboxing or method overriding. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `opened`, `closed`?

Comment: well you can't, try using uppercase or mangled words

Comment: Alternative what? Names? Languages? Structures?

Comment: Alternatives in the sense, convert to strings or something else.

Comment: @MadProgrammer What?

Comment: uppercase, constants are usually uppercased.

Comment: @PrinceBansal As an alternative ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wished StackOverflow could be tolerable to humour.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will suit your purposes?

```
public enum RuleScopeType {
    PRIVATE("private"),
    PUBLIC("public");

    private final String keyWord;

    RuleScopeType(String keyWord) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord;
    }

    public String getKeyWord() {
        return keyWord;
    }
}
```